# method onAction does not return desired type of page

Tags: tapestry

TML

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>            
        <!-- link should return /tracker -->
        <t:pagelink page="tracker" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle disabled">
        <span>All Tickets</span>
        </t:pagelink>
    </li>
    <t:loop source="projectList" value="projectP1">
        <!-- link should return /tracker/# -->
        <li><t:pagelink page="tracker" context="${projectP1.id}">${projectP1.title}</t:pagelink></li>
    </t:loop>
</ul>
...
<t:actionlink t:id="followProject">
    <t:if test="isUserFollowingProject"> Unfollow</t:if> 
    <t:if test="!isUserFollowingProject"> Follow</t:if> 
</t:actionlink>
```

Java

```
@Property
private Project project;
...

@PageLoaded
void onPageLoad() {
    projectList = projectDao.loadAll();
    ticketList = ticketDao.loadAll();
}

void onActivate(Integer contextValue) {
    if (contextValue != null) {  
        project = projectDao.getByID(contextValue);
    }
    if (project != null) {
        List ticketListByProjectID = ticketDao.getTicketsByProjectID(project.getId());
        if (!ticketListByProjectID.isEmpty()) {
            ticketList = ticketListByProjectID;
        }           
    }
}

@CommitAfter
void onActionFromFollowProject() {

}
```

So the problem is when I'm on project context with url like `../tracker/1`, and I click on the actionlink, it returns me to /tracker home page with out `/1` context, where instead, I want it to return `/tracker/1`, the same context as it was when I clicked on action link.  How can I fix this, since I have two type of context, an empty one and with a number ?

**p.s. I tried following:**

```
Integer onPassivate() {
    return project != null ? project.getId() : null;
}
```

Now this works, and returns context with `tracker/1` when I click on actionlink, however, my pagelink:

```
<t:pagelink page="tracker" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle disabled">
        <span>All Tickets</span>
</t:pagelink>
```

Now has value of `tracker/1`, instead of `/tracker`, when I added this `onPassivate` method

**UPDATE:**

I'm not using onPassivate method. Every other page link normally works, expect actionlink for follow/unfollow. So for code in tml

```
<t:actionlink t:id="followProject" t:context="tracker/${project?.id}" class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-default-gradient">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
    <t:if test="isUserFollowingProject"> Unfollow</t:if> 
    <t:if test="!isUserFollowingProject"> Follow</t:if> 
</t:actionlink>
```

in developer tool on inspect that actionlink element I have following html code:

```
<a class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-default-gradient active" href="/IssueTracker/tracker.followproject/tracker$002f1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span> Unfollow</a>
```

Does this `href="/IssueTracker/tracker.followproject/tracker$002f1"` tell you maybe something ? It stills returns me to `/IssueTracker/tracker` instead of `IssueTracker/tracker/#1, 2, 3...` page.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to tell the link itself to use the project as the `context` parameter. This should do the trick:

```
<t:actionlink t:id="followProject" t:context="project">
    <t:if test="isUserFollowingProject"> Unfollow</t:if> 
    <t:if test="!isUserFollowingProject"> Follow</t:if> 
</t:actionlink>
```

The passivate option will add the value to all links linking to this page (like you experienced).

Comment: Without onPassivate method and with new context to actionlink like u said, `t:context="project"` or `t:context="project.id"` same problem is happening, I'm getting redirected to `/tracker`. However with added context to actionlink, and written onPassivate method, `<t:pagelink page="tracker" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle disabled">
        <span>All Tickets</span>
</t:pagelink>` has a link value of `tracker/1` current project that is selected.. Any ideas ?

Comment: It's really strange when I have written `<t:pagelink page="tracker" >` , it changes on the project select and gets value of `<t:pagelink page="tracker/1" `

Comment: Even if I add context to actionlink like `t:context="tracker/${project.id}"` it redirects me back to `/tracker`. On inspect element it shows it as: `<a href="../tracker.followproject/tracker$002f1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span> Unfollow</a>`

Comment: You should remove the onPassivate method altogether. Also in your code I see no eventhandler for the event method so use the pagelink in stead like so.  `<t:pagelink page="tracker" context="project?.id">link</t:pagelink>`. If that does not work, your project parameter will be null for some reason.